# numpy.core.multiarray : Solution for specific version

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to install one python package called VESPA, for which I want specific version of NumPy that is NumPy 1.21.0

But for this I get an error
`numpy.core.multiarray failed to import`

Is there any possible solution specifically for mentioned version of NumPy?

Comment: The 'vespa' tag is used for the https://vespa.ai search and recommendation engine, not the VESPA project on pypi.org. I don't know if that project has its own tag, as I was unable to find one.

Comment: Tried  !pip install numpy==1.21  ?

Comment: @cinderashes I tried to install that specific version. But got the same error. This error can be solved by updating NumPy to the latest version but in that case VESPA won't work.